# Edit a subset of a file

Tags: linux, bash

When dealing with large files it is often useful to use commands like `head`, `tail`, to look at subsets of a file.

I'm wondering if there is a utility for editing subsets files? I just encountered a situation where I wanted to edit the first line of a file, and ended up loading the whole thing into `vim`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `sed`(stream editor), to replace `foo` with `bar`

```
# edit 1st line
sed -i '1s/foo/bar/g' file.txt

# edit line 10~20
sed -i '10,20s/foo/bar/g' file.txt
```

There's many commands in `sed`, read the [doc](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html).